# Git add single subdirectory recursively

Tags: git, git-add

I know I can add everything in my working directory with the following syntax:

```
git add .
```

I also know I can add the contents of a subdirectory with this syntax:

```
git add subdir/*
```

But how do I add everything (recursively) in a single subdirectory? I imagine it looks something like this:

```
git add subdir/.
```

Comment: `git add subdir` should be enough

Comment: `git add subdir/.` should work as well.  Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git add subdir` will add subdir and everything in it recursively.